# How can I make my function only accept odd numbers into my array, and reject even numbers? C++

Tags: c++

Let me preface this by saying I am fairly new to functions and arrays.
I have to make 3 functions: Function1 will be user input, Function2 will determine even/odd numbers, and Function3 will display the contents. I have Function1 and Function3 complete, and will post below, but I'm having a difficult time with Function2. What I have now will give the user an error message if they enter an even number, but it's messed up, and I just can't seem to figure out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
 
void getUsrInput(int num[], int size) //function for user input (function 1 of 3)
{
    int n;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter five odd numbers: ";
        cin >> n; 

        num[i] = n;

        if (num[i] % 2 != 0) //if the number is odd then store it, if it is even: //function for even or odd (function 2 of 3 *doesn't work)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid input. Please only enter odd numbers!" << endl; //let the user know to enter only odd numbers. 
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{   
    const int size = 5; //array size is 5 numbers
    int num[size]; 

    getUsrInput(num, size);

    cout << "D I S P L A Y - PART C/B" << endl;
    cout << "========================" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {       
        cout << num[i] << endl; //function for display (function 3 of 3)
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "it's messed up" mean?

Comment: You increment `i++` twice if odd number is inputted.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik originally when I would compile this, and I entered "1,2,3" it would stop at 3 numbers and the output would be "1, memory location, 3, memory location" etc. I don't know it was just a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

increments `i` each time through the loop.

```
if (num[i] % 2 != 0) {
    i++;
}
```

increments `i` each time the number is odd. So each time the user inputs an odd number, `i` gets incremented twice. Change the loop control to

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; }
```

so that `i` only gets incremented on valid input.

Comment: ah I see now. I thought I needed the increment in the loop control so that it would continue to accept numbers until 5 numbers were reached. Literally just removing that fixed the problem. Thank you a lot because this would have taken me hours on my own

Answer (score 0):

It' perfect for a while loop and you only count up if the insert is ok:

```
void getUsrInput(int num[], int size) //function for user input (function 1 of 3)
{
    int n, i=0;

    while( i < size )
    {
        cout << "Enter five odd numbers: ";
        cin >> n;

        if (n % 2 == 0) 
            cout << "Invalid input. Please only enter odd numbers!" << endl; 
        else 
            num[i++] = n;   // ok then store and count up        
    }
}
```

Comment: Turns out I was doing it wrong. I can't have the determining whether its even or odd in the same function as user input. So now I have to figure that out. I have to have an entire function for this.

Comment: if (n % 2 == 0)  -> even number
if (n % 2 != 0)  -> odd number

n is you input and you check it with if () and store them if ok or not in num[i++]. ++ means you count up after using it.